# Soft question: meaning of 'disjoint' (i.e. is it edge or vertex disjoint?) in definition of a fan.

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I am working throuhg some questions of graph theory, and in one of the question I am given the definition:

> Let $B\subset V(G)$ and $a$ be a vertex not in $B$. An $a$-$B$ fan is a family of $|B|$ paths from $a$ to $B$, disjoint except at $a$.

I am not sure if by 'disjoint' we mean edge-disjoint, or the stronger condition 'vertex disjoint' (clearly if it is vertex disjoint, it must be edge-disjoint). I have not come across the definition of an $a$-$B$ graph online, only a fan-graph $F_{n,m}$ which is something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a handful of cues which all point towards the “vertex-disjoint” interpretation:

1) If it were merely edge-disjoint, there would be no (immediate) need to specify “except at $a$”.  In fact the expression “edge-disjoint except at $a$” is already suspect: if two paths are *not* edge-disjoint at $a$ then it’s because they share an **additional** vertex besides $a$.  So it seems odd to call this “except at $a$” rather than “except at edges incident to $a$”.

2) If it were only edge-disjoint, there would be no special significance to having $|B|$ paths, since they wouldn’t be forced to cover all of $B$.

3) Many terms in graph theory tend to be vertex-oriented by default if not otherwise specified: chromatic number vs edge-chromatic number; $k$-connected vs $k$-edge-connected.  And of course, the size of a graph $|G|$ is customarily the number of vertices, not edges.

Taken together, the evidence is strong that edge-disjoint is not the intent.  If we relaxed the definition to merely edge-disjoint, then it might allow an $(a,B)$-fan (where $|B|=3$ and $b \in B$ is adjacent to $a$) to consist of 3 copies of the exact same edge from $a$ to $b$.  After all, those paths are edge-disjoint allowing for the exception at $a$ (yes they also meet at $b$, but see discussion at point 1) and there are 3 of them.

It’s hard to believe someone would want to define the term “fan” to include such an outcome.

Comment: Thsank you for the reply. I realised over reading it through again that 'except at a' probably answered the question. But I was also wondering, you mentioned that the 'paths would not be forced to cover all of B'. But as it stands I don't think they have to? It seems to me that a fan exists f there is at least one path from a to one vertex in B, having a length |B|? If the context helps, the question is:

Comment: For a set B ⊂ V (G) and a vertex a not in B, an a-B fan is a family of |B| paths from a to B, disjoint except at a. Show that a graph G (with |G| > k) is k-connected if and only if there is an a-B fan for every B ⊂ V (G) with |B| = k and every vertex a not in B.

Comment: @Meep Note that “$|B|$ paths” is unhyphenated here.  It refers to the *number* of paths, not the length of each one.  Since there are $|B|$ paths and each one ends on a vertex of $B$ (necessarily distinct due to vertex disjointness, assuming $a \notin B$ which is probably fair), this consumes all vertices of $B$.

Comment: Haha. I am ashamed; and to think English is my first language when I don't pick up on such nuances. Thank you!

Comment: This answer is great and I am only adding my own to provide a reference that everything in it is correct.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you!  The reference is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*, the definition is

> Given a vertex $x$ and a set $U$ of vertices, an **$x,U$-fan** is a set of paths from $x$ to $U$ such that any two of them only share the vertex $x$.

This leaves out the condition about having exactly $|U|$ paths, but later quotes Dirac's Fan Lemma as saying

> A graph is $k$-connected if and only if it has at least $k+1$ vertices and, for every choices of $x,U$ with $|U|\ge k$, it has an $x,U$-fan of size $k$.

In the most interesting case, we take $|U|=k$, and then the number of paths is $|U|$ as well.